# Advice on using Recurrent Neural Networks for non-time series dataset

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, rnn

I'm testing different machine learning algorithms for predicting week-to-week fantasy football scores for individual players. For those who don't know, fantasy football is a game in which players pick a "team" of American football players each week and based on their statistical performance that week they are asigned a score. Each position scores points based on their own statistics, so for instance a QB gets 4 points for each touchdown pass it throws, a RB gets 1 point for each 10 yards it runs, etc.

What I am doing is taking the last 5 years of stats for each player in each position (filtering for those who started more than 5 games each season) and calculate the 1, 5 and 10 moving average of each particular statistic. So, for instance, for each game of player X who is a QB I have the previous game number of touchdown passes thrown, the 5 game moving average of touchdown passes thrown and the 10 game moving average of touchdown passes thrown. Repeat for every statistic. I also added each of their rivals' defensive statistics for each game, in the same vein: 1, 5 and 10 moving averages of every relevant statistic.

I used this dataset to run linear regression, SVM, Bayesian regression and MLP models, with results similar to the benchmark of "fantasy football experts" that give their predictions each week. I split the datasets 70-30 randomly for train-test, and used 20% of the train set for validation. The problem is that the error is very large anyway: MRE is over 50%, with a std of 30-50% too (it's the same for experts, but still).

I was wondering if RNNs wouldn't perform better. The problem is that I don't know if I should feed the NN with the same dataset (with the moving averages instead of each game's statistics) or if I should build a time series for each player instead. In which case: with 5 seasons for each player (each season 16 games or less) I have at most 90 datapoints for each player. Would that be enough for a RNN? And would it be fair to compair the performance of the RNN with the performance of the other models, which I trained with a different training set and validated with a different validation set and test set, since in this case I'll have to set apart one season (or a number of seasons) for prediction?

I'm new to deep learning models, so I'm basing this on what I read on the subject: I'll have to build a time series of each game of each player and starting with one game I'll let the model predict the performance of each subsequent game in the series like this?

```
    t_1             t_2                    t_i            t_(i+1)        t_(i+2)                    t_n
 _________      _________               _________      _________      _________               _________
| full    |    | full    |             | full    |    | empty   |    | empty   |             | empty   |
| game    |----| game    |---- ... ----| game    |----| game    |----|  game   |---- ... ----|  game   |
|_________|    |_________|             |_________|    |_________|    |_________|             |_________|
     ^              ^                       ^              ^              ^                       ^
     |              |                       |              |              |                       |
  use to          use to                 use to         predict        predict                 predict
  train           train                  train
```

Or is this not necessary and I can feed the neural network with my samples the same way I fed the other models their samples? I'm mostly confused because I've seen these sort of models applied to samples that don't necessarily fit a "time series" frame, like image processing where each sample doesn't have a time condition relation with other samples.